# How do you set the text in an NSTextField?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextfield

I'm trying to set the text in an NSTextField, but the `-setStringValue:` and `-setTitleWithMnemonic:` methods are not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your NSTextField referenced as an IBOutlet and attached properly (if you're using Interface Builder that is...)

Answer (score 241, accepted):

`setStringValue:` is the way to do it.  You should make sure your outlet is being set properly. (In the debugger, make sure your textfield variable is not null.)

Comment: The way to do this in Swift is just `stringValue`, then you can set it to whatever string you want.

Answer (score 49):

Just do something like this:

```
myLabel.stringValue = @"My Cool Text";
```

Answer (score 20):

Just `myLabel.stringValue = "MY TEXT"` works here, using Swift and Xcode 6.

Comment: This is a good answer for the most recent dev environment. Btw why is this not part of the NSTextField documentation? I went there first and thought it would be really obvious to find how to do this, but it was not there...

EDIT: I found it, it is just not in the obvious place of "Topics", because stringValue is actually a property of parent class NSControl, and appears in "Overview"

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 4**

```
self.yourTextField.stringValue = "Your_Value"
```

Note: Fetching value from self.yourTextField.stringValue at that will get warning message i.e. 
[image: Warning Message]
To avoid this kind of warning you can use like this (suggested way)

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
 your code ... 
}
```

OR also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391367/swift-4-uiapplication-registerforremotenotifications-must-be-called-from-mai/44392584#44392584).

Answer (score 2):

If the value you're trying to set happens to be an integer rather than a string, you don't need to convert the integer value to a string manually; you can just call:

```
myLabel.integerValue = i;
```

The `integerValue` property is defined on `NSTextField`'s parent class, [`NSControl`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol?language=objc). See that linked documentation page for a full list of methods it supports.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectiveC:

```
[label setStringValue: @"I am a label"];
```

original code I use in my code to display application version is:

```
    [lblVersion setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"v%@", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]]];
```

Answer (score -3):

just do this

```
[textField setString:@"random"];
```

Comment: wrong. This is how you set up a `UITextField`. The question is about Cocoa NSTextField that is a different animal.