# NSTableView.reloadData() for NSTextFields

Tags: swift, refresh, nstableview, nstextfield, reloaddata

I'm working on a little mac application on swift, and I have not been swifting for very long, but am aware of the function reloadData() for NSTableViews. In my program, I incorporate the function controlTextDidChange for an NSTextField. I would like to be able to refresh that artificially, using a function comparable to reloadData() for NSTableViews, except for NSTextField, but have been unable to find such a function. Does one exist? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a `reloadData()` function for `NSTextField`. Normally, to set the text you would do something like: [How do you set the text in an NSTextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841559/how-do-you-set-the-text-in-an-nstextfield)

If you need to do more than just change text (reload the text field's view properties??), why don't you move your `NSTextField` setup code into a method and then just call that when you need to "refresh" the text field.