# Main Thread Checker Warnings coming from Sinch Video Library

Tags: sinch

I'm using SinchRTC 3.11.1 in my IOS App. When I enter a video chat the following warnings are being produced because of the Sinch library. A few UI API calls are being done from a background thread instead of the main UI thread. Can these be fixed within the library?

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: 96751, TID: 7066961, Thread name: Sinch Worker Thread, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d7eb41 -[SINClientImpl onPubSubSubscriptionConnectionEvent] + 66
5   XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d7ec84 -[SINClientImpl onPubSubSubscriptionSuccess:] + 197
6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108740a3c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010874093a _CFXRegistrationPost + 442
8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108740682 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108702a02 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1826
10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108701b7c _CFXNotificationPost + 652
11  Foundation                          0x0000000109ec0172 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
12  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d9b8c7 -[SINPubSubscriber notify:userInfo:] + 336
13  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d9ba46 -[SINPubSubscriber subscribeDidSucceedOnChannel:sequence:withRequestedTimetoken:] + 220
14  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d92515 -[PubnubSubscriber request:withInitialTimeToken:didSucceedWithResponse:] + 435
15  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d920d5 __43-[PubnubSubscriber subscribeWithTimeToken:]_block_invoke + 111
16  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d909ce __52-[PubnubService performRequest:onSuccess:onFailure:]_block_invoke.42 + 143
17  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d8ffc9 -[PubnubRequestOperation operationWillFinish] + 284
18  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d6902d -[SINQRunLoopOperation finishWithError:] + 70
19  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d68536 -[SINQHTTPOperation finishWithError:] + 41
20  CFNetwork                           0x0000000107f7e0e5 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 53
21  CFNetwork                           0x0000000107f7e00a -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 198
22  CFNetwork                           0x0000000107f7df32 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 48
23  CFNetwork                           0x0000000107f823b3 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 100
24  CFNetwork                           0x00000001081283cb ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 100
25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110e8a658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110e8fe6b _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 589
27  CFNetwork                           0x0000000107f7de04 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext13_invoke_blockEPKvPv + 24
28  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001086f35d8 CFArrayApplyFunction + 72
29  CFNetwork                           0x0000000107f7dcda _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 132
30  CFNetwork                           0x0000000107f7db78 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 282
31  CFNetwork                           0x0000000107f7d9ab _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 65
32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108747e71 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010872c56f __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
34  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010872bb1f __CFRunLoopRun + 1039
35  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010872b499 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
36  Foundation                          0x0000000109eda22e -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 274
37  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105cf8bd8 _ZN4base20MessagePumpNSRunLoop2017-07-12 12:20:51.360149-0700 XXXXXX[96751:7066961] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: 96751, TID: 7066961, Thread name: Sinch Worker Thread, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d7eb41 -[SINClientImpl onPubSubSubscriptionConnectionEvent] + 66
5   XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d7ec84 -[SINClientImpl onPubSubSubscriptionSuccess:] + 197
6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108740a3c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010874093a _CFXRegistrationPost + 442
8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108740682 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108702a02 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1826
10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108701b7c _CFXNotificationPost + 652
11  Foundation                          0x0000000109ec0172 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
12  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d9b8c7 -[SINPubSubscriber notify:userInfo:] + 336
13  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d9ba46 -[SINPubSubscriber subscribeDidSucceedOnChannel:sequence:withRequestedTimetoken:] + 220
14  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d92515 -[PubnubSubscriber request:withInitialTimeToken:didSucceedWithResponse:] + 435
15  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d920d5 __43-[PubnubSubscriber subscribeWithTimeToken:]_block_invoke + 111
16  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d909ce __52-[PubnubService performRequest:onSuccess:onFailure:]_block_invoke.42 + 143
17  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d8ffc9 -[PubnubRequestOperation operationWillFinish] + 284
18  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d6902d -[SINQRunLoopOperation finishWithError:] + 70
19  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d68536 -[SINQHTTPOperation finishWithError:] + 41
20  CFNetwork                           0x0000000107f7e0e5 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 53
21  CFNetwork                           0x0000000107f7e00a -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 198
22  CFNetwork                           0x0000000107f7df32 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 48
23  CFNetwork                           0x0000000107f823b3 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 100
24  CFNetwork                           0x00000001081283cb ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 100
25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110e8a658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110e8fe6b _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 589
27  CFNetwork                           0x0000000107f7de04 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext13_invoke_blockEPKvPv + 24
28  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001086f35d8 CFArrayApplyFunction + 72
29  CFNetwork                           0x0000000107f7dcda _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 132
30  CFNetwork                           0x0000000107f7db78 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 282
31  CFNetwork                           0x0000000107f7d9ab _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 65
32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108747e71 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010872c56f __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
34  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010872bb1f __CFRunLoopRun + 1039
35  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010872b499 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
36  Foundation                          0x0000000109eda22e -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 274
37  XXXXXX                    0x0000000105cf8bd8 _ZN4base20MessagePumpNSRunLoop
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView layer]
PID: 96751, TID: 7066464, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.sinch.SINVideoCapturer.session, QoS: 25
Backtrace:
4   XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d66f4f -[SINVideoCapturer startWithPreset_sq:frameRate:] + 505
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110e8966d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110e8a658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110e9308c _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1173
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110e93aa5 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 342
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110e96d3b _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 785
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110e969c7 _dispatch_worker_thread4 + 54
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001112ed616 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001112ed0f1 start_wqthread + 13
2017-07-12 12:20:52.112965-0700 XXXXXX[96751:7066464] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView layer]
PID: 96751, TID: 7066464, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.sinch.SINVideoCapturer.session, QoS: 25
Backtrace:
4   XXXXXX                    0x0000000105d66f4f -[SINVideoCapturer startWithPreset_sq:frameRate:] + 505
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110e8966d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110e8a658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110e9308c _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1173
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110e93aa5 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 342
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110e96d3b _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 785
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110e969c7 _dispatch_worker_thread4 + 54
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001112ed616 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001112ed0f1 start_wqthread + 13
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because Xcode 9 features a new main thread checker that checks whether UI API's are executed in Main thread. UI operations are bound to cause problems in a non-main thread. You have to update your **SinchRTC** to fix this runtime issue. The developers of **SinchRTC** should patch this and release an update. Hope this helps. For more info., refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44392584/5912335).

Answer (score 0):

The library should fix theses errors but if you want to disable it you can do it in the scheme, in the Diagnostics option.

[image: Example]