# Google placepicker not running on main thread warning

Tags: ios, google-places-api

I noticed that with an update to xcode 9, a run-time warning message pops up when presenting Google Place Picker:

> UI API called from background thread

```
present(GooglePlacePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I am pretty certain that I am calling that from the main thread, but in case I wasn't I tried fetching main thread first:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    self.present(self.GooglePlacePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)      
})
```

I noticed that this is only an issue for Google Place Picker, as I've tried the same thing with Google Autocomplete and I receive no such warning. I'd imagine that this may have something to do with additional UI components in Place Picker built in to the iOS SDK but was wondering if anybody was able to prevent this warning. Otherwise, I would assume that Google would address this in the next SDK release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in **Google PlacePicker** SDK code, not yours. Its up to them to fix this issue. Track the SDK for latest version. They must've patched it by now as they have already done for Firebase SDK recently. If there is no update on this, you'll have to wait until they fix it.

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44392584/5912335) here explains more about this runtime issue if you want to check it out.

Comment: Yea I figured that was the case. I'd assume next update takes care of this, but just in case I submitted this as an issue.

Comment: Yep. There seems to be lot of things to take care when it comes to iOS 11 and Xcode 9 in general. Hope they release the patched version soon.