# FIRMessaging should be called from main thread only

Tags: ios, firebase

I am using intel [multi-os-engine](https://multi-os-engine.org/) to build my iOS-app. When trying to setup Firebase Messaging I get the following error:

> *** Assertion failure in -FIRMessaging teardown, /Users/hpbaxxter/StudioProjects/app/ios/xcode/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/FIRMessaging.m:374
>       2019-01-24 15:13:15.988333+0100 SkipAndGo[4195:75192] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRMessaging should be
>   called from main thread only.'
>
> *** First throw call stack: (  0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000000177921bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x0000000016d30735 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000017791f42 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98  3
>   Foundation                          0x0000000013de9940
>   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 166  4
>   SkipAndGo                           0x000000000b5b512a -[FIRMessaging
>   teardown] + 234  5   SkipAndGo
>   0x000000000b5b3da3 -[FIRMessaging dealloc] + 195  6   libobjc.A.dylib 
>   0x0000000016d42dcc _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 202  7
>   ???                                 0x0000000044f6ec79 0x0 +
>   1157033081 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of
>   type NSException

I already read Q&A's like this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391367/uiapplication-registerforremotenotifications-must-be-called-from-main-thread-o).

This is my Code when setting up FIRMessaging:

```
Globals.dispatch_async(Globals.dispatch_get_main_queue(), new Globals.Block_dispatch_async() {
            @Override
            public void call_dispatch_async() {
                FIRMessaging.alloc().setDelegate(CLOUDMESSAGES_DELEGTE);
                application.registerForRemoteNotifications();
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint at FIRMessaging.m:374 and backtracing to see where the deallocation comes from.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I got this call stack (see my edit)

Comment: You should use the class method messaging to get the instance. Looks like you are creating a new instance, and the `FIRMessaging` throwing this error.

Comment: @SachinVas omg you are right! Please write an answer so I can accept it. OMG I was looking for the error for so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the class method `messaging` to get the instance. Looks like you are creating a new instance instead of using the messaging() method.

Answer (score 0):

This method return what you want.

```
/**
 *  FIRMessaging
 *
 *  @return An instance of FIRMessaging.
 */
+ (instancetype)messaging NS_SWIFT_NAME(messaging());
```